# Jquery table sorter pagination not showing total pages

Tags: jquery

I'm not using table sorter but using pagination script alone from tablesorter plug in.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("tableid").tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});

});
```

I'm not getting total page in the text box.Why is it empty? Am,i missing any plug in.

I used this alone from that script. src="addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"

Comment: this might be helpfull [table sorter stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094423/tablesorter-pager

Comment: @Parag:I did n't find any things there.

Answer (score 2):

There might be problem with selector u used

you have used `$("tableid")`

but in actual what **`tableid`** is ?

if it is id u have to use `$("#tableid")` selector. and if it is class then use `$(".tableid")` .

Comment: :I've used it in my code correctly but it was wrong here.Not this problem.The problem is in some other place.