# Table not being divided into pages

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Steps to reproduce :

Click the append button more than 10 times on - http://jsfiddle.net/fXAbh/6/ 
Expected result : The table should be divided into pages.
Actual result : The table is not divided into pages.

I tried adding     `$("#myTable").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}).tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});` to the end of append() function
so that every time the table is appended to it's refreshed, but this is not working.

UPDATE : 
The table is divided into pages if the table is sorted(by clicking on a column name) after there are more than ten rows in the table.

Comment: I don't the plugin has proper support for update and pager plugin. You should try jQuery datatables or jqGrid plugin which has proper support.

Comment: I did notice that once you've appended 10 times, sorting the results (by Name or anything else) does re-configure the paging appropriately.  You could trigger such a sort at the end of your append function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a known issue with dynamically adding content to a paged table:

[Need Help with Jquery TableSorter Pager plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836680/need-help-with-jquery-tablesorter-pager-plugin)